# Irrelevant IntentChooser option while starting Webbrowser from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I have added a button to be shown at Notification, as per condition if the notification contains http, it will show "Show Images/Videos" button. Below is the code for same.

```
else if (!iurl.isEmpty()) {
            builder.addAction(R.drawable.noticon, "Show Images/Videos", resultPendingIntent);
```

and here is code for resultPendingIntent.

```
if (iurl.contains("http")) {
            Log.i(TAG, "http");
            intent1.putExtra("action", "http");
            intent1.putExtra("url", iurl);
            intent1.putExtra("id", ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION);
            resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                            mCtx,
                            ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION,
                            intent1,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                    );
```

Above code is working fine and I have receiver where when user clicks on button, the action for same is defined as below.

```
if (bundle.containsKey("action")) {
                    actiontype = bundle.getString("action");
                    if (bundle.containsKey("url")) {
                        url = bundle.getString("url");
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received action: " + actiontype);
                    if (actiontype != null && actiontype.equalsIgnoreCase("http")) {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent1.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent1);
                    }
                }
```

But now, this code is not opening chrome to launch url instead it pop up intent chooser with irrelevant options like dialer, maps etc. to select for action.

In case I change ACTION_VIEW with Normal activity of app, everything works fine.

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help:

```
void open(Activity activity, String url) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("googlechrome://navigate?url=" + url);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    if (i.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) == null) {
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    }
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: woh, it worked, but we do not need all this in case of activity, then what special in broadcast?